# Ngrx: combine two selectors

Tags: ngrx

I've built this `IStore`:

```
export interface IStore {
  user: IUser;
  sources: ISourceRedux;
}
```

where `IUser` is:

```
export interface IUser {
    id: string;
    cname: string;
    sname: string;
    ...
}
```

and `ISourceRedux` is:

```
export interface ISourceRedux {
    entities: { [key: string]: ISource };
    ids: Array<string>;
    selectedIds: Array<string>;
    editingSource: ISource;
    defaultId: string;
}
```

So, I've created these selectors:

```
export const getSourcesState = (state: IStore) => state.sources;
export const getSelectedIds = (sourceRdx: ISourceRedux) => sourceRdx.selectedIds;
export const getSelectedSourceIds = createSelector(getSourcesState, fromSources.getSelectedIds);
```

So, up to now, in order to check if a user is logged I did that:

```
this.store$
  .select(fromRoot.getUserState)
  .filter(user => user.id != null && user.logged)
  .do(user => this.store$.dispatch(...))
  ...
```

Now I'm strugling for getting user information and selectedSourceIds at the same time in order to check if:

1. a user is logged (`this.store$.select(fromRoot.getUserState)`
2. then get all selectedSourceIds (`this.store.select(fromRoot.getSelectedSourceIds)`)
3. dispatch an action

How could I get this?

Comment: have a look into `withLatestFrom` RxJs operator

Comment: The accepted answer should be the one from @DeborahK

Answer (score 47):

Would it make sense to add that code to a selector:

```
// Selector functions
const getProductFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<ProductState>('products');
const getUserFeatureState = createFeatureSelector<UserState>('users');

export const getCurrentProduct = createSelector(
  getProductFeatureState,
  getUserFeatureState,
  getCurrentProductId,
  (state, user, currentProductId) => {
    if (currentProductId === 0) {
      return {
        id: 0,
        productName: '',
        productCode: 'New',
        description: 'New product from user ' + user.currentUser,
        starRating: 0
      };
    } else {
      return currentProductId ? state.products.find(p => p.id === currentProductId) : null;
    }
  }
);
```

This code is in the product.reducer file. Here I define the feature selector both for the products and for the users.

I then build a `getCurrentProduct` selector using both the product and user feature.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. That's the way the official doc does it: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors

Comment: I am getting empty state instead of state with the value. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing what you are doing. Consider doing a separate question with your specific code. Common possible issues: a path missing a `return`, calling the selector before the data is retrieved.

Comment: Is this still supposed to work? I get an error that `MemoizedSelector<ProductPartialState, ...` is not compatible with `MemoizedSelector<UserPartialState,..`

Answer (score 12):

This is my solution:

```
this.store$.combineLatest(
      this.store$.select(fromRoot.getUserEntity),
      this.store$.select(fromRoot.getSelectedSourceIds),
      (store, user, selectedSourceIds) => ({user: user, selectedSourceIds: selectedSourceIds}) 
    )
    .filter((proj) => proj.user.id != null && proj.user.logged)
    .do((proj) => this.store$.dispatch({type: 'DELETE_CARDS', payload: {username: proj.user.username, tokens: proj.selectedSourceIds}}))
    .take(1)
    .subscribe();
```

I hope it's useful.

Comment: I think that this approach does not take advantage of reselect (memoized selectors) as explained with consequences here https://netbasal.com/lets-talk-about-select-and-reselect-in-ngrx-store-177a2f6045a8

Answer (score 2):

I created a feature selector that combines two features to accomplish this.

The feature selector for the global module:

```js
export interface ScaffoldPartialState extends GlobalPartialState {
  readonly [SCAFFOLD_FEATURE_KEY]: State;
}
```

which I import to the Scaffold selectors and have `ScaffoldPartialState` extend it.

```js
export interface ScaffoldPartialState extends GlobalPartialState {
  readonly [SCAFFOLD_FEATURE_KEY]: State;
}
```

The `createFeatureSelector` only returns the state typed so that the returned type looks like it contains only the state for this feature.
The value is the complete application state, but the type makes it looks like it's only for one module.
By one type extending the other, the resulting type provides a property for both modules.

`AppState`

```js
{
  module1: { ... },
  module2: { ... },
  module3: { ... }
}
```

`Module2PartialState`

```js
{
  module2: { ... },
}
```

`Module2PartialState extends Module3PartialState`

```js
{
  module2: { ... },
  module3: { ... }
}
```

This way the `ScaffoldPartialState` feature selector works for selectors of both modules.

Example:

```js
export const getAuthorizedMenuItems = createSelector(
  getScaffoldState,
  GlobalSelectors.getUserPermissions,
  getMenuItems,
  (_globalState, userPermissions, menuItems) =>
    userPermissions ? menuItems.filter(e => userPermissions.checkAllPermissions(e.permissions)) : []
);
```