# rxjs combining observables from ngrx store returning undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to combine 2 selectors from my ngrx store.
Both selectors work fine and are tested.

However when i try to combine them, the subscription logs undefined. I have tried using combineLatest too but that didn't even let me subscribe.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Code:

```
lookId;
products$;
prod;

constructor(private store: Store<CoreState>,
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private looksService: LooksService)

ngOnInit()
this.products$ = forkJoin(this.looksService.getILooks(), this.looksService.getIProducts());
this.products$.subscribe(res => this.prod = res);
console.log(this.prod);
```

Comment: forkjoin is a nogo, it will shouldnt emit with your current implementation as the selectors never complete, and forkjoin waits for the source observables to complete, collects their last values and emit them together

Comment: what do you mean by combineLatest didnt let you subscribe?

Comment: btw, the console log will always be undefined, as the value of prod is set asynchronously

Comment: @Jota.Toledo thanks for the info about forkJoin. when using combineLatest it doesn't recognise subscribe as an available method (or pipe etc).

i get the following error when using combineLatest and trying to use subscribe: 


operators_1.combineLatest(...).subscribe is not a function

and the error on VSCode:
[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'UnaryFunction<Observable<{}>, Observable<[{}, ILook[], IProduct[]]>>'.


(ILook and IProduct are the models of data returned from the selectors).

Comment: where are you importing combineLatest from? please update your question with the relevant code, add the explicit type of products$ and the signatures of your service methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ngrx: combine two selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257027/ngrx-combine-to-selectors)